# Can I add a check for zero to this line

Tags: matlab

I have the following code line:

```
stitched(1+offset(2):h1+offset(2),1+offset(1):w1+offset(1),:) = double(I1(1:h1,1:w1,:));
```

How can I alter it so it will take the value `double(I1(1:h1,1:w1,:))` only for the cells in `stitched` which are zero?

I already have some data in `stitched` I want to preserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change should set it up:

```
stitched(1+offset(2):h1+offset(2),1+offset(1):w1+offset(1),:) = ...
    stitched(1+offset(2):h1+offset(2),1+offset(1):w1+offset(1),:) + ...
    double(I1(1:h1,1:w1,:)).*(stitched(1+offset(2):h1+offset(2),1+offset(1):w1+offset(1),:)==0);
```

**Explanation:**

Lets note `stitched` as `S`
`I1` as `I`, and
`1+offset(2):h1+offset(2),1+offset(1):w1+offset(1)` as `a:b,c:d`.

So we get:

```
S(a:b,c:d,:) = S(a:b,c:d,:) + I(a:b,c:d,:).*(S(a:b,c:d,:)==0)
```

Now it's clearer, if the value in `S(a:b,c:d,:)` is not `0`, then

```
I(a:b,c:d,:).*(S(a:b,c:d,:)==0) = 0
```

and the whole statement becomes:

```
S(a:b,c:d,:) = S(a:b,c:d,:) + 0 % <-- No change
```

Otherwise, `S(a:b,c:d,:)` is zero, and the statement becomes:

```
S(a:b,c:d,:) = 0 + I(a:b,c:d,:).* 1 % <-- the value in I
```

you may need to cast some parts of the statement, but it should work.